# ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("EnvironmentName"."Project name"."ID") in ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I created an app "from a  file"(xls) and the project was created successfully, I can see the rows. The original table does not have "ID" apparently that was added automatically when creating the app on APEX. I am trying to add a new row but it doesn't give me the text field for "ID" , so when I put all the data to add a new row, it complains with this message. How can I make the ID to be added automatically? Or any other way around to stop getting this error?

Comment: Check the table definition for id column. Is it auto identity? You can alter the id column to be identity ‘columnname   NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCRE

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set the ID column (in Apex) as "not required" and populate it in the database, using a database trigger. Usually, it is a sequence that does that.

First, find ID's current MAX value as

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN

SQL> select max(id) from test;

   MAX(ID)
----------
      7654
```

Sequence should start at 7655:

```
SQL> create sequence seq_test_id start with 7655;

Sequence created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := seq_test_id.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing

```
SQL> insert into test (ename) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7655 Littlefoot

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As it works from SQL*Plus, it'll work from Apex as well.

---

Another option is to create a **process** in Apex which would do:

```
:P1_ID := seq_test_id.nextval;
```

---

Or, if your database version is high enough (12c and above), you could use an **identity** column. Unfortunately, you can't alter table and *modify* existing ID column to the identity column. If you can afford it, create a new column to be used as an ID.

```
SQL> alter table test add new_id number
  2    generated always as identity
  3    start with 7655;

Table altered.
```

Unfortunately, you can't set it to "old" ID values:

```
SQL> update test set new_id = id;
update test set new_id = id
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32796: cannot update a generated always identity column
```

So, if this is OK with you:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID ENAME      NEW_ID
---------- ------ ----------
      7369 SMITH        7655
      7499 ALLEN        7656
      7521 WARD         7657
      7566 JONES        7658
      7654 MARTIN       7659
```

then just drop the old ID column and rename new column to its "old" name:

```
SQL> alter table test drop column id;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test rename column new_id to id;

Table altered.

SQL> select * from test;

ENAME          ID
------ ----------
SMITH        7655
ALLEN        7656
WARD         7657
JONES        7658
MARTIN       7659

SQL>
```