# Oracle Apex. SQL Workshop. ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Database 23c Free - VirtualBox Appliance for Developers.

Created two tables using the Apex Object Browser. First table - table1 (id, name). I inserted rows from a pre-prepared set into one table.

After this, if I try to insert a row through the Apex Object Browser, I get `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into table1.id.`

I decided that i was out of sequence and ran this command

```
ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY id GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH LIMIT VALUE);
```

But it didn't solve the problem. I got `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into table1.id.`

I inserted row with command `INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES ('test')`. The row has been added and  ID has the correct (following) value.

If i try to insert a row through the *Apex Object Browser*, I again get `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into table1.id.`

In the second table I can insert a row through the Apex Object Browser without any problems.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please see if this is of any help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905354/ora-01400-cannot-insert-null-into-environmentname-project-name-id-in-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the '[on null](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAIGEJE)' clause in the identity column definition

`...id generated by default on null as identity start with limit value`

You'll find APEX is constructing an insert statement with null as the value, as nothing has been defined for that column. The DDL will ensure a value is given.

The use a process to fetch the sequence value will also work, but I think this would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to alter an existing column to an identity column. The `ALTER TABLE` statement you posted will reset an existing identity column to start with the next available value. It will not modify the column to be an identity column and it will raise an error.

Instead: rename the existing column, add a new identity column, update the identity column with existing column value, alter the identity column to start with next available value.

```
koen 19c >CREATE TABLE tab1 ( id    NUMBER NOT NULL ,value VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL );

Table TAB1 created.

koen 19c >INSERT INTO tab1 ( id ,value ) VALUES ( 1 ,'foo' );

1 row inserted.

koen 19c >ALTER TABLE tab1 RENAME COLUMN id TO id_old;

Table TAB1 altered.

koen 19c >ALTER TABLE tab1 ADD id NUMBER
  2*    GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 );

Table TAB1 altered.

koen 19c >UPDATE tab1 SET id = id_old;

1 row updated.

koen 19c >ALTER TABLE tab1 MODIFY id GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( START WITH LIMIT VALUE );

Table TAB1 altered.

koen 19c >ALTER TABLE tab1 DROP COLUMN id_old;

Table TAB1 altered.

koen 19c >INSERT INTO tab1 ( value ) VALUES ( 'bar' );

1 row inserted.

koen 19c >select * from tab1;

VALUE       ID 
________ _____ 
foo          1 
bar          2 

koen 19c >
```

But... since this is testing, just drop your test table and recreate it with an identity column, that is much faster.